# React Native - TextInput does not get updated and is stuck with its initial state which is empty onSubmitEditing

Tags: react-native

The setSearchTerm does not get updated and is stuck with empty string all the time when i hit "done" on the keyboard. Any suggestions?

```
          // React Native Bottom Navigation
      // https://aboutreact.com/react-native-bottom-navigation/
      import React, { useState }  from 'react';
      import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Dimensions, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, TextInput  } from 'react-native';
      import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
      import
      MaterialCommunityIcons
      from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
      const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
      const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
      const SearchScreen = ({navigation}) => {
        const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
        const [data, dataSet] = useState({})



        const onSearchText = async() => {

          alert(searchTerm);
          
          dataSet({});
          let txtSearch = searchTerm;
          if(txtSearch.length > 0){
          //alert(searchTerm);

            let response = await fetch('https://xxxxxx',{
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
              },
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: searchTerm }),
              mode: 'no-cors',
            })
                response = await response.json();
                alert(JSON.stringify(response.results));
                //alert(JSON.stringify(response.results));
                dataSet(response.results);
        

          }else{

          }

        }

        React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
          navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => 
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <TextInput 
            
            placeholder='Search Here'
                      onChangeText={term => setSearchTerm(term)}
                      onSubmitEditing={onSearchText} style={{backgroundColor:'#B2DFDB',marginRight:20,width:windowWidth - 125, padding:5, borderRadius:5,}}/>
            
            
            </View>
            ,
          });
        }, [navigation, ]);



        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (

              

          <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Display", { url: item.url, youtube: item.youtube })}>
          <View style={{flexDirection:'row', marginBottom:20,padding:10,backgroundColor:'#B2DFDB',borderRadius:10,}}>
              
          <View pointerEvents="none" style={{}}>
                  <WebView style={{width:200, height:130, }} source={{ uri: item.url }} />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ marginLeft:10, }}>
                  <Text style={{color:'#00796B', flexWrap: 'wrap',}}>{item.source}</Text>
                  <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flex:1,}}>
                  <Text style={{color:'#000000', fontWeight:'bold', flex:1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>{item.title}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <Text style={{color:'#00838F', }}>{item.category}</Text>
                  <Text style={{color:'#00838F', }}>{item.country}</Text>
                  </View>
          </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        );
        return (
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 , padding: 16, backgroundColor:'#E0F2F1',}}>

            {

              data.length > 0 ? (
                <FlatList
                style={{flex:1,}}
                  data={data}
                  renderItem={renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />) : <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center', }}><Text style={{color:'#80CBC4', fontSize:20, textAlign:'center'}}>Nothing found, please try and search again.</Text></View>

            }


            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        );
      }
      export default SearchScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't currently have a value assigned to the textInput field.  Adding a value of searchTerm should resolve it.

```html
 React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
          navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => 
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <TextInput 
            
                    placeholder='Search Here'
                      onChangeText={term => setSearchTerm(term)}
                      value={searchTerm}
                      onSubmitEditing={onSearchText} style={{backgroundColor:'#B2DFDB',marginRight:20,width:windowWidth - 125, padding:5, borderRadius:5,}}/>

            
            </View>
            ,
          });
        }, [navigation, ]);
```

Comment: I added the value, but every time i type the letters get deleted on the textinput

Comment: Still having problems with the above comment

Comment: You may be having issues because you have it inside of the useLayoutEffect, which fires after every DOM mutation.  Perhaps try pulling this function outside of the useEffect.

Comment: i have done what you said i moved this out:

navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => 
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
            <TextInput 
            
                    placeholder='Search Here'
                      onChangeText={term => setSearchTerm(term)}
                      value={searchTerm}
                      onSubmitEditing={onSearchText} style={{backgroundColor:'#B2DFDB',marginRight:20,width:windowWidth - 125, padding:5, borderRadius:5,}}/>

            
            </View>,
          });

but now the keyboard dissapears

Comment: navigation.setOptions can stay inside the hook, and you can bring in your component in the headerRight function.  So headerRight: () => <MyNewComponent />